# Order of the VPN connections in the VPN menu

Tags: vpn

Is it possible to change the order of the VPN connection in the OS X VPN Menu?

[image]

Comment: and you could not just simply drag it to the top position ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename them ;).  They are ordered alphabetically.  If you put a white space (edit: or any other name that precedes in the alphanumeric order) in front of the second VPN's name in System Preferences > Network (by selecting the VPN Service and clicking on the cog symbol below the services: click "Rename Service..."), then un-tick and re-tick "Show VPN status in menu bar", the order will change.